# How can discord bot send message and attachment to a specific user after a job done

Tags: discord.py

I am having a discord bot which takes job requests from user DM.
The job may take a few minutes and produce a file which should be sent back to the user.

I can fetch message.author.id from the async def on_message(message), and the job will be execute once the message received. Due to the job takes a while, the bot would report error as it is hanging on the job process. Therefore I have used subprocess to run the job, but now, I have not got any idea how the job could communicate to the bot and let it know as completed and send the message and attachment to the specific user.

And how about if the user is offline, would the message and attachment get delivered??

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == None or message.content == "":
        return
    msg_ = message.content
    author_ = str(message.author)
    return_code = subprocess.call("start JOB.py msg_ author_", shell=True)
```

Comment: If the main process is killed (e.g. due to a timeout), then the subprocess will also be killed. Consider using a messaging broker to decouple message received, job processing, and message return.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but my main question is how to let the JOB.py to tell bot to send message? what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think one potential way of doing it is keeping track of which jobs are running/have been triggered by users. Either through a file or database. The file and DB options would allow you to possibly decouple the job running/discord part as well.

You could then use a [`task`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) that runs periodically to check the dict/file/db for finished jobs and then send a message to the user that it's done. It can then either delete the job or set a "message_sent" flag or equivalent so it doesn't send the notification multiple times.

The job script as part of it's cleanup/finish can then mark itself as complete within the file/db so that the "notify when job finished task" can pick that up and inform the user.